# macro to refresh webservice functions

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has stock data pulled in using the webservice function and I refresh it using Alt-Ctrl-F9. I am trying to create a macro that will do the same function as Alt-Ctrl-F9 but I haven't had any luck. I have tried recording myself pressing those buttons, I've tried

```
Activeworkbook.RefreshAll  
DoEvents
```

and I have also tried

```
ActiveSheet.Calculate
```

So far, I am having no luck...

Comment: Did you really try to create the macro?  It gives the answer...

Comment: trying to get it to be part of a bigger macro and I don't want to have to manually click those functions every 15 minutes just so my other macro will work correctly.

Comment: I see now what you are saying. When I recorded my steps, it gives me the first of your two answers and it didn't work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  That makes sense then.  I have had similar issues when working with third party UDFs especially when they return different results even for the same parameters.  I don't think it's possible to get the `FullRebuild` version from the recorder.

Comment: Beats me. I have been attempting to find my way around macros for the last week and half. Most of these things just go right over my head right now. Hopefully when I get my Macros book I'll start catching up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
Application.CalculateFull
```

or

```
Application.CalculateFullRebuild
```

The former is the one that is used if you record a macro while hitting <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F9</kbd>.  The latter is a more thorough version which rebuilds the calculation tree.  See [CalculateFullRebuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822609.aspx)  and [CalculateFull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194064.aspx) at MS support for the full story.

Comment: Beautiful! i used the latter of the two. I should have posted this a long while ago... Thanks for the help.